# Python can't import module from package

Tags: python, module, package, virtualenv, flask-restful

I have a flask restful project with the following layout (file names changed for convenience)

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    common/
        __init__.py
        util.py
    foo/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        utilities.py
```

`foo/` is just a folder containing code for one of the API endpoints, I'm planning to add others in the future, for this reason I have `common/util.py` file which contains reusable functions that I will use with other API endpoints.

**`foo/main.py`**

```
from flask_restful import Resource, request

from utilities import Analysis

class Foo(Resource):
    def get(self):      
        pass
```

in `foo/utilities.py` I have classes with methods that get some data, I import those classes to `foo/main.py` to return JSON response

classes in `foo/utilities.py` also uses some functions from `common/util.py` but when I try to import something from `common/util.py` to `foo/utilities.py` I get `import common.util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'`

What could be causing this? I tried importing various ways:
`from common.util import my_func`
`from .common.util import my_func`
`from myproject.common.util import my_func`

but none worked.

This is `myproject/app.py` in case it matters:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

from foo.main import Foo

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Foo, '/Foo')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I'm doing all of this in activated virtualenv if it matters

Comment: What Python version? Py2 and Py3 have different rules about implicit relative import.

Comment: @phd I'm using python 3

Comment: Have you installed `myproject`? Or you simply run `foo/main` as a script without installation? In the latter case `myproject` is not available in `sys.path`, only directory `foo` is and it's not a package so you cannot use relative import.

Comment: What do you mean by installing? I don't run `foo/main.py` I run `myproject/app.py` to run the whole API, it runs fine but the import of `common.util` fails in `foo/utilities.py`, to test it I run `foo/utilities.py` and I get the error I wrote above

Comment: Putting a copy of `myproject` into `site-packages/` directory of the current Python (or any directory that's already in `sys.path`) by running `python setup.py install` or [`pip install`](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html). Of course you have to have [`setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from common.util import my_func

In Python 3 this is an absolute import, that is, the directory with `common/` subdirectory must be in `sys.path`. In your situation it's certainly a wrong approach.

> from .common.util import my_func

This import expects `common` to be a subdirectory of `foo` which is also not the case.

> from myproject.common.util import my_func

This is finally the best approach but for it to work the parent directory of `myproject/` subdirectory must be in `sys.path`. Either you install the entire `myproject` or add the parent directory to `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable or add the directory to `sys.path` in `foo/main.py`. Something like:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/to/parentdir /home/to/parentdir/myproject/foo/main.py
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/to/parentdir')
```

`/home/to/parentdir` is the directory where `myproject/` is.

After installing `myproject` or adding its parent directory to `sys.path` you can also use relative import. You need to remember that `common` is a sibling package comparing to `foo` so the import must be not from `.common` but from `..common`:

```
from ..common.util import my_func
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

in `myproject/app.py` I added the following at the top:
`import sys
sys.path.insert('path/to/parent/of/myproject')` and everything is fine. Only problem is that in `foo/utilities.py` I have to use absolute import like `from myproject.common.util import` but that'll do for the time being

Comment: `sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/parent')` not `sys.path.insert('path/to/parent')`